# Use values saved to a file in order to compute mean/median/mode/etc

Tags: python, file-io

I have a program that saves a file that you can write values to. What I am trying to do is use the saved files to calculate my mean/median/mode and to be able to delete values. functions. I am able to add values to the file through the open("filename","a")...but how do I make it so that I am able to import the file values to calculate my other functions?

Sorry its so long, but if anyone can help I would really appreciate it, I am new to figuring out File IO a stuff.

```
filename = input("What do you want to name your file? Be sure to include .txt after the filename!:")

def main(filename):

    print("Now what would you like to do?")
    print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Press 1 if you would like to ADD a Value to your list")
    print("Press 2 if you would like to DELETE a Value from your list according to its value")
    print("Press 3 if you would like to DELETE a Value from your list according to its location")
    print("Press 4 if you would like to DISPLAY your List")
    print("Press 5 if you would like to COMPUTE MEAN for your list")
    print("Press 6 if you would like to COMPUTE MEDIAN for you list")
    print("Press 7 if you would like to COMPUTE MIDPOINT for you list")
    print("Press 8 if you would like to COMPUTE MODE(S) for your list")
    print("Press 9 if you would like to COMPUTE STANDARD DEVIATION for your list")
    print("Press 10 if you would like to READ values from a FILE you have made")       
    print("Press 0 if you would like to EXIT")
    print()


    execute = int(input("which action would you like to do next?"))
    if execute == 1:
        add_Values(filename)
    if execute == 2:
        remove_Value_List(filename)
    if execute == 3:
        del_Value_Location(filename)
    if execute == 4:
        read_file(filename)
    if execute == 5:
        computing_Mean(filename)
    if execute == 6:
        computing_Median(filename)
    if execute == 7:
        computing_Midpoint(filename)
    if execute == 8:
        computing_Modes(filename)
    if execute == 9:
        computing_Standard_Dev(filename)
    if execute == 10:
        read_file(filename)
    if execute == 0:
        print()
        print("That's too bad I was having so much fun...but okay...bye!")
    if execute >= 12:
        print("Sorry but that is not one of the options")
    if execute <= -1:
        print("Sorry but that is not one of the options")

def add_Values(filename):
    fout = open(filename,"a")

    again = 'y'
    while again == 'y':
        fout.write(input("Enter a number you want to write to the file:")+"\n")
        print("Do you want to add another number?")
        again = input("y = yes, anything else = no:")
    fout.close()
    print("The numbers have been saved to the file")

    main(filename)

def remove_Value_List(filename):
    fout = open(filename, "r")
    fout.readlines()
    remove = "y"

    while remove == "y":
        print()
        print("Here is your list:")
        add_Values(filename)
        number_list = float(input("Which value should I remove?"))

        try:
            values.remove(number_list)
            print("Here is the revised list:")       
            print()
            print()
        except ValueError:
            print("That item is not found in the list.")
            number_list = float(input("which value should I remove?"))
        remove = input("Would you like to remove a value? y = yes, amything else = no:")
    fout.close()
    print()

    main(filename)
def del_Value_Location(filename):

    remove = "y"
    fout = open(filename,"r")
    fout.readlines()

    while remove == "y":
        print()
        print("Here is your list:")
        add_Values(filename)
        number_list = int(input("Which position should I remove?"))

        try:
            del values[number_list]
            print("Here is the revised list:")       
            read_file_one(filename)
            print()
        except ValueError:
            print("That item is not found in the list.")
            number_list = float(input("which value should I remove?"))
        remove = input("Would you like to remove a value? y = yes, amything else = no:")
    fout.close()
    print()

    main(filename)

def computing_Mean(filename):

    with open(filename,"r") as fout:
        summ = 0
        cnt = 0
        for line in fout.readlines():
            cnt += 1
            summ += float(line.strip())
        print ("Mean value is:" (summ/cnt))

def computing_Median(filename):           

    fin = open(filename,"r")
    fin.readlines()
    ordered = sorted(filename)
    length = len(filename)
    print("The median of this list is:")
    print(float((ordered[length//2] + ordered[-(length+1)//2]))/2)

    main(filename)

def computing_Midpoint(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as fout:
        filename.sort(key=int)
        minNum = min(float(filename))
        maxNum = max(float(filename))
        print("The midpoint of this list is:")
        print((minNum + maxNum) / 2)

    main(filename)

def computing_Modes(filename):

    from collections import Counter
    data = Counter(filename)
    print("The Mode(s) of this list is/are:")  
    print(data.most_common(1))

    main(filename)

def computing_Standard_Dev(filename):

    mean = sum(filename)/len(filename)
    for i in values:
        total = 0
        newDev = i - mean
        squared = newDev**2
        total = (total + squared)
        divider = (total/(len(values)-1))
        standardDev = divider**.5
    print("The standard deviation is:")
    print(standardDev)

    main(filename)


def read_file(filename):

    fin = open(filename, 'r')
    L = fin.readlines()

    for ix in range(len(L)):
        L[ix]=L[ix].strip()

    while "" in L:
        L.remove("")

    for ix in range(len(L)):
        L[ix]=float(L[ix])
    fin.close()

    print(L)
    main(filename)       

main(filename)
```

Comment: There is no main_two function in the code if I'm not mistaken. What does main_two do?

Comment: I took main_two out in order to condense it, but main_two just brings up the menu in main...i just did not know how to be able to have the options come back up with the values that got inputed...if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of errors in your code which are very similar to each other so I will explain only one of those similar ones and you should fix others by examining fixed one.

For startes you are opening a file named `filename`. Using quotes around it makes it a string. You should use it like this:

```
def add_Values(filename):
    fout = open(filename,"w")
```

But using `with` statement to open files is much more better because file is closed automatically even if exception is raised.

```
def add_Values(filename):
    with open(filename) as fout:
    #do smth
```

There is no file to work with in `def del_Value_Location(filename):` and some others. You should open your file in those as well.

To make calculations you need read your data from your file. Which can be achieved by using file.readlines()

```
def computing_Mean(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as fout:
        summ = 0
        cnt = 0
        for line in fout.readlines():
            cnt += 1
            summ += int(line.strip())
        print ("Mean value is: %.1f" % (summ/cnt))
```

If you want to change how many digits you want to see, you should change `%.1f` part.
With this you should fix your other computations by yourself.

About menu, you can do something like this to make it appear again without using a second function.

```
filename = input("What do you want to name your file? Be sure to include .txt after the filename!:")
#exclude this filename in main and use it as `main`s argument.
def main(filename): 

    print("Now what would you like to do?")
```

Ofcoure after this, you should change all `main_two()`s to `main(filename)`.

Comment: Okay, and now I can not figure out how to get my other functions to import the filename and execute properly. Is there any way you could help me with that as well?

Comment: I tried to explain the errors I see. Please try to fix others by looking this one. If you have any other questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: So if I use the with open(filename,"w") I do not need to close it? It will close by itself?

Comment: Yes. It will close itself and by the way, if you open a file using "w" it will erase the existing one. Lets say, you called add values once and then if you call it again previous values will be deleted. So you it'd be better if you open files to write in "a" (append) mode if you are going to use that file to write again.

Comment: Okay first, thank you so much for all the help! I really appreciate it! But okay, I used the Mean function you made, but it keeps saying "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"...I am trying to fix it and get the str to a float, but it is not working.

Comment: It works fine for me by just c/p from here. Have you checked your filename variable?

Comment: Yeah, I c/p it, what do you mean have i checked my filename variable?

Comment: My code shows the float value by one digit. You don't need to change it to anything by float(smth).

Comment: Okay, I got the mean to work :) now is it going to be similar when trying to calculate the other calculations?

Comment: Yeap. You will get your numbers by reading them and use them how you want to use.